# Drop Down Navigation Menu Hides All the Page Contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have created a DropDown navigation menu in CSS. when i click on it, it hides the page contents altogether. I want want that instead of hiding the page content, either it pushes page content down or drop down menu should be on front end of the page content.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".menu-toggle-btn").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
            $(".navigation-menu").toggleClass("active");
        });
    </script>
```

```css
body{
    /*font-family:Calibri !important;*/
    font-family:ProximaNova,Arial,Sans-serif;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:12px;
    /*max-width: 100%;*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header{
  height: 45px;
  background: #008269;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}

.inner-width{
  max-width: 100%;
  /*padding: 0 10px;*/
  margin: auto;
}

.navigation-menu{
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 45px;
}

.navigation-menu a{
  /*margin-left: 10px;*/
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1% 10%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: .3s linear;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-menu a:hover{
  background: #fff;
  color: #2f3640;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-menu i{
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-toggle-btn{
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1500px) {
  .menu-toggle-btn{
    display: block !important;
    margin-top:13px;
    margin-right:13px;
  }

  .navigation-menu{
    position:center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    /*max-width: 100%;*/
    background:#008269;
    top: 45px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    /*padding: 20px 40px;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .navigation-menu::before{
    content: "";
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #172b4d;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 10px;
  }

  .navigation-menu a{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .navigation-menu.active{
    display: block;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Responsive Drop-down Navigation</title>
      <link href="css/MasterPage-CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
</head>
<body>    

   <form id="form2" runat="server"> 
    <header>
          <div class="inner-width">
            <i class="menu-toggle-btn fas fa-bars"></i>
            <nav class="navigation-menu">
                 
                <a href="#"">Products</a> 
                <a href="#"">Customers</a>
                <a href="#"">Sales</a>
                <a href="#"">Installments</a>
                <a href="#"">Financial</a>
                <a href="#"">Stock</a>
                <a href="#"">payroll</a>
                <a href="#">Expensis</a>

            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
       
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentBody" runat="server">
           <div style="overflow-x:auto;"></div>        
       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </form>
     
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".menu-toggle-btn").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
            $(".navigation-menu").toggleClass("active");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `float: left;` on wrap content div element

```js
$(".menu-toggle-btn").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
    $(".navigation-menu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
    /*font-family:Calibri !important;*/
    font-family: ProximaNova, Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    /*max-width: 100%;*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    height: 45px;
    background: #008269;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.inner-width {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*padding: 0 10px;*/
    margin: auto;
}

.navigation-menu {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 45px;
}

.navigation-menu a {
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 1% 10%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: .3s linear;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-menu a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #2f3640;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-menu i {
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-toggle-btn {
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1500px) {
    .menu-toggle-btn {
        display: block !important;
        margin-top: 13px;
        margin-right: 13px;
    }

    .navigation-menu {
        position: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*max-width: 100%;*/
        background: #008269;
        top: 45px;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
        /*padding: 20px 40px;*/
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .navigation-menu::before {
        content: "";
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid #172b4d;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        right: 10px;
    }

    .navigation-menu a {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .navigation-menu.active {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <header>
        <div class="inner-width">
            <i class="menu-toggle-btn fas fa-bars"></i>
            <nav class="navigation-menu">

                <a href="#"">Products</a> 
            <a href=" #"">Customers</a>
                <a href="#"">Sales</a>
            <a href=" #"">Installments</a>
                <a href="#"">Financial</a>
            <a href=" #"">Stock</a>
                <a href="#"">payroll</a>
            <a href=" #">Expensis</a>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentBody" runat="server">
        <div style="overflow-x:auto; float: left;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem totam delectus aspernatur veritatis deleniti repellat dignissimos recusandae alias odio necessitatibus cupiditate tempora, soluta voluptatum fuga non possimus officiis maiores culpa?
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic voluptas repellat deleniti laudantium rem nobis magni labore. Libero dolore fuga facere, beatae commodi voluptate assumenda repellendus, aperiam magnam voluptates consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil voluptate blanditiis illo corrupti sunt pariatur soluta, laborum voluptates veniam facilis. Neque possimus natus assumenda enim magnam reprehenderit quas omnis voluptas?
        </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```